# IOS 9.2: My "General> Profiles and Device management" is gone?

Tags: ios, settings

I have looked and looked and I can't find a solution. I need to get to the profiles and device management section on my ipad 3 but it is not under general. I tried searching for it in settings and it shows up as an option. I tap on it and it just opens General, where there is no option for profiles and device management. Please help, I already tried restarting the device.

How can I find it?

Comment: And, your question is?

Comment: Weird, it shows up for me on my iPhone 6s running iOS 9.2. Right there under General. Apple did apparently changed the name from Profiles to Device Management in iOS 9.2, though.

Comment: Thebro21, My question is how do I find it. I thought it would have been implied given the simplicity of my post.Sorry about that, my bad.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Power off then turn on your iOS device, there you see "Device Management" on your "General - Settings" under VPN settings

Comment: I too have this problem. The option is not there. Is there an event that needs to occur in order to have it show up? It's an iPhone 5 with iOS 9.3.1.

Comment: Yes. There's an event which needs to occur to get it to display. You need to click to install one of your enterprise apps and when the dialogue box appears stating that the app is from an untrusted source click "Cancel". The act of doing this adds the menu item. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html under Manually Trusting an Enterprise Developer. If the dialogue says Done/Retry instead of Cancel, reboot your phone to clear cache.

Comment: Also, it was not showing up and I found it came up after a long wait as my phone is almost full

Comment: I believe it may only show up if you have a profile installed—do you?

Comment: i definitely have provisioning profiles installed on my iPhone 6 (iOS 10.2) and i can't find the settings anywhere. it shows up in a search for "profiles" and then redirects me to settings > General... help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This option will not be displayed if you do not have an installed profile. You don't actually install profiles from the settings. Profiles can be installed through different channels, whether it be an email invitation or a website. The only reason profiles show up in settings is so you can manage/delete them easily. Before I had profiles, I didn't have the settings option to manage them.